# How do I write on a file after altering it with filehandle in python?

Tags: python, filehandle

The purpose of this program is to backspace three times in a data file:

```
ofile = open(myfile, 'r')
file = open(myfile, 'r')

with open(myfile, 'rb+') as filehandle:
   filehandle.seek(-3, os.SEEK_END)
   filehandle.truncate()
```

I then attempted to add additional text after this by switching to the "write" function:

```
ofile = open(myfile, 'r')
file = open(myfile, 'r')

with open(myfile, 'rb+') as filehandle:
   filehandle.seek(-3, os.SEEK_END)
   filehandle.truncate()

ofile = open(myfile, 'w')

ofile.write('*')
```

This, however, overrides the entire data set and writes only "*" on a blank document. How do I add to the file without removing the rest of the content?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the append flag, instead of write. So, `ofile = open(myfile, 'a')`